# Connect .mxml component to another

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.5, flexbuilder, flex4.6

How can i click a button on an .mxml component to open a specific selectedItem on a spark List from another .mxml component!?
Thanks ;-)

Comment: Add some code or more details about the arrangement/relationship of the classes, is one the parent of the other, are both contained in some other component and so are siblings?

Answer (score 0):

First off this is pretty basic so I'll recommend you watch these video tutorials on ramping up for Flex: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/videotraining.html

What does "open" mean?

Depends on the arrangement of the components in terms of what the best way to do this is, you can achieve it through either Binding or dispatching an event.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!! (I already, of course, watch those videos, thanks) I have on a mxml a List that on selectedItem give me some text , so from other .mxml (not Main) i want to go directly to the mxml that have the List and imediatly open the specific selectItem i want!! The both components are called to a container independently from eachother in the Main App.

Comment: @Rpgccv, okay best way I can think of is to dispatch an event that you capture at a point where they have a common ancestor then make a call to update the list accordingly.  Something like dispatchEvent(new Event("myObjectAction", true));  This will make a bubbling event that is dispatched, then at the common ancestor you'd do, myInstance.addEventListener("myObjectAction", function(event:Event):void {otherChild.theList.selectedItem = event.target.data}); or something along those lines.

Comment: If this starts to get too hairy in terms of going up and down the chain you may want to look into the various methods of creating a "model" object that you update in the one instance and bind to in the other.  If you're going to pursue this you can checkout Swiz or Robot Legs or other micro-frameworks, or just keep it simple and do it yourself managing the "singleton" model (only creating one instance in the app then getting a reference through a static method).

Comment: Sorry for assuming you hadn't seen those vids I just thought they had some example that was relatively similar and I think they're a good starting point for anyone.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i think i didn't understand the whole explanation but i'm going to give it a try. I'll post here my attempts!!

Comment: @Rpgccv no problem post back once you've made progress and I'll try to give better guidance